# Adding Bounds to Method Level Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, methods

I'm working or a project for mapping between DTOs and domain objects. As part of the mapping process I have the following interface:

```
public interface DomainObjectLookup {

  <T> T lookup(final Class<T> type, final Long id);

}
```

In the Mapper class, we use the lookup

```
private final DomainObjectLookup lookup;
public Employer fromDto(EmployerNoNameDto dto) {
final com.bizo.dtonator.domain.Employer o;
      if (dto.id != null) {
        o = lookup.lookup(com.bizo.dtonator.domain.Employer.class, dto.id);
      }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that I want to add additional restrictions to the generic type in a class that implements DomainObjectLookup. If I have an interface like

```
public interface HasId {
  public Long getId();

  public void setId(Long id);
}
```

and a child class of DomainObjectLookup

```
final class StubDomainLookup implements DomainObjectLookup {

  private final Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public void store(final Long id, final Object instance) {
    objects.put(key(instance.getClass(), id), instance);
  }

  @Override
  public <T> T lookup(Class<T> type, Long id) {
    final T instance = (T) objects.get(key(type, id));
    if (instance == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Instance not found " + type + "#" + id);
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private static String key(final Class<?> type, final Long id) {
    return type + "#" + id;
  }

}
```

how can I specify that 'T' must implement 'HasId'?

Comment: `T extends HasId` ?

Comment: Like @Ramanlfc said, just define in as `<T extends HasId>`. But be aware that it needs to be done in the interface and not the implementation, else it wont compile

Comment: When you say in the interface, do you mean DomainObjectLookup? If so, that wouldn't work since not every subclass needs to implement HasId.